# How does one get the attributes of a circuit from its DAG in qiskit?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I have the following code, which runs properly.

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.converters import *

ghz2 = QuantumCircuit(5, 5)
ghz2.h(2)
ghz2.cx(2, 1)
ghz2.cx(1, 0)
ghz2.cx(2, 3)
ghz2.cx(3, 4)


ghz_dag = circuit_to_dag(ghz2)
```

How do I access properties of this dag? For instance, I would like to get all the 2-qubit gates using the [collect 2qubit gates method](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/transpiler/passes/collect_2q_blocks.py) (the output is supposed to be a dictionary) or simply draw the DAG but again, dag_drawer(ghz_dag) throws up an error (`'MultiDiGraph' object has no attribute 'number_of_selfloops'`) even though, that's done in an example [here](https://medium.com/qiskit/terra-0-7-better-visualization-compilation-memorization-895b05b7197f).

Maybe this is just a Python usage question but how does one access the properties of the DAG?

Comment: Hi, which versions of qiskit are you running? I am unable to recreate this

Comment: @met927 if I type conda list, I see 0.13.0 under the version for qiskit. I am running the commands from the question in the Spyder IPython console after restarting the kernel.

Comment: Ah ok, that is good. Which version of networkx are you running?

Comment: @met927 I'm using 2.4. Just to add, it's not only the specific dag_drawer that I'm having trouble with - it'd be good to know generally how to access these various properties of the dag. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties of the DAG are simply accessed using dot notation. For example, if you would like to get all the two qubit gates you would do `dag.twoQ_gates()` which returns a list of the two qubit gates present in the dag.

The code you have linked to is a transpiler pass. This is a method that looks over the dag to identify some property or to perform some optimization. It stores variables to the property set, `self.property_set`. There is more information about using the transpiler [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/fundamentals/5_using_the_transpiler.ipynb).

Comment: When I run, for example, ghz_dag.twoQ_gates(), I see the following output [<qiskit.dagcircuit.dagnode.DAGNode at 0x1f5aa0ddc08>,
 <qiskit.dagcircuit.dagnode.DAGNode at 0x1f5aa0ddc88>,
 <qiskit.dagcircuit.dagnode.DAGNode at 0x1f5aa0dd808>,
 <qiskit.dagcircuit.dagnode.DAGNode at 0x1f5aa0ddf08>]. How do I see this as a list or a dictionary where I can read off the gate and what qubits it acts on?

Comment: This is a list, of type `DAGNode`. From the `DAGNode`s you can read all the properties of the node, for example `node.op` will get you the operation that corresponds to this node. You can see the whole class [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/dagcircuit/dagnode.py)

Comment: Thank you - that was very useful! I assume dag_drawer doesn't work because of networkx? In any case, these methods are very helpful!

Comment: Happy to help! Yes I think it might be a networkx issue